# Symfony Vhost is not working?

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am using XAMPP in Windows.I want to set vhost for my symfony project so I have set the vhost in apache through (httpd-vhosts.conf) file as :

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

# This is the configuration for drberg.com
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName drberg.com.local
  DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/DrBerg.com/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/DrBerg.com/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf "D:/xampp/htdocs/DrBerg.com/web/sf"
  <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/DrBerg.com/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So I can't access it it's not opening anything also when I access my symfony project through manual link so it redirects me to my localhost as :

```
http://localhost/DrBerg.com/web/
```

So it redirects me to :

```
http://localhost/xampp/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in your `hosts` (in WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/) your *ServerName*:

```
127.0.0.1        drberg.com.local
```

(it works immediately after save this file)

and point to:

```
http://drberg.com.local
```

*(use **http://** because sometimes chrome send the address to google.com instead go there)*

and don't use *localhost* in the *ServerName* because XAMPP filter this word (*local* can be).